# Flutter - Error - BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter

I try to "stack" 2 widgets, the first is a background and the next is a tree-node (Text+icon).

So, I use the flutter Stack widget, but when I use StackFit.expand, I got the following error message:

"BoxConstraints forces an infinite height"

Here is the code, I tried to fix it, but no way:

```
  Widget _buildNodeWidget() {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green, width: 110, height: 60)),
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red, width: 100, height: 50)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

What I try to achieve is to have a fading background when the mouse is over.

[image]

Noticed that this widget is inside a scroll widget and this
on cannot accept any child with an infinite height.
So, if I try this, I do not see the green background.
So, maybe to fix this I just need a way to have the Container using all the stack sizes.

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
children: [
Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
Text("HELLO WORLD")
],
);
}

So, the real version should looks like this:

```
  Widget _buildNodeWidget() {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: isMouseHover(),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
      GestureDetector(
          onSecondaryTapDown: (details) => _handleSecondaryTap(details),
          child: _buildNodeWidgetBasic())
    ]);
  }
```

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: could you include an ui image of what you want?

Comment: I copy pasted your code but dont see any issues. Please provide more of the code so we can see whats going on?

Comment: It seems it is because this widget is inside a Scroll widget, which cannot contains any widget with infinite height. So, I can remove the StackFit.expand, but then the background is not visible anymore :-(